# Ensuring that memory cache is properly invalidated

Tags: c, dma

So I have a piece of code that looks like the following:

```
uint8_t *buffer = <16 MB memory region>
uint32_t count = 1024;
uint32_t position = 0;

uint8_t *get_data() {

    uint8_t *region = buffer + position * 16;

    position += 1;
    position %= count;

    do {
        __sync_synchronize();
    } while (reigon[0] != 1);

    return region;
}
```

The buffer in question is being written to by a hardware device. At some point (maybe before we started looping, maybe after we've started), the hardware will write to that location, as well as to the rest of the buffer.

I'm currently using __sync_synchronize to issue a memory barrier, because I would like to ensure that there is no way that the compiler would cause the rest of that memory region to be cached from any time before `region[0] == 1`.

I'm aware that I could mark the entire buffer as volatile. However, I'd like to be able to return a non-volatile buffer from this function.

So, is there any way to do a `__sync_synchronize`, but only have it target the range of memory that I specify. In this case the memory from `[region, region + 1024)`?

*As an aside, this code is living in userspace. The memory buffer is a pinned region of memory that I've allocated with a kernel module, mapped into userspace, and told a FPGA to eventually DMA to it. This is essentailly attempting to implement a polling mechanism on the FPGA finishing a DMA tranfer.*

Comment: Is there a problem with casting the region to a volatile uint8_t *?

Comment: @VaughnCato: I'm fine with doing just about anything within this function. I don't, however, want to change the return value of the function.

Comment: What hardware are you running on?  Does your ISA have more specific memory barrier instructions?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: Relatively recent x86_64 hardware. I believe the current machines are Intel. At the low end, this should support something like an Intel Core 2 Duo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A region-limited memory fence would be a fairly unusual architectural feature.  However, you only need the fence after the loop has terminated:

```
while (*(volatile uint8_t *)region != 1)
    ;

__sync_synchronize();
return region;
```

Comment: That's actually a really good point. At the very least I should move to this.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
uint8_t *get_data() {    
    uint8_t *region = buffer + position * 16;
    volatile uint8_t *volatile_region = region;

    position += 1;
    position %= count;

    do {
    } while (volatile_region[0] != 1);

    return region;
}
```

Comment: Do I have any guarantee that `region[1]` does not have a cached value from a time before `region[0] == 1`?

Comment: Also, as an aside. This is more or less what the code used to look like. I was concerned about data corruption because of cached data which is what caused me to add the __sync_synchronize.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem since you aren't accessing any data through "region" in the same function.

Comment: strict aliasing doesn't apply to cv-qualifier differences anyway.

Comment: Isn't a compiler allowed to inline this function, and then reorder the accesses of region and volatile_region as it wants?

Comment: _By the way, I would love for this to be completely correct. I just honestly don't trust the compiler to not be overly agressive with the optimization and cause issues._

Comment: I suppose that is true in theory, but you could get around that in practice by putting get_data() in a separate compilation unit.

Comment: But I would assume that LTO would break that as well.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, if you use it.